# Labels “a)”, “b)”, "c)", "d)" below and to the left of each subfigure

Tags: subfloats

I want to produce one figure that contains four subfigures and label “a)”, “b)”, "c)", "d)", below and to the left of each subfigure, just like the picture shows.

I searched the Internet, but I only found the method of labeling "a" or "(a)" and did not find the result of "a)" and left justifying.

So, there are two requirements: "a)" and left justifying of four subfigures.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us what you've tried so far. In particular, which LaTeX package(s) do you employ to create the subfigures? That's important information, as it affects the way the subfigure captions' labels may be modified to meet your formatting objectives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- you not provide any information about your document, so the used document class and packages for sub figures are unknown to us
- one solution in the case that your document class is `article` and that you use the `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[skip=0.5ex, belowskip=1ex,
                labelformat=brace,
                singlelinecheck=off]{subcaption}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.40\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Subfigure a}
        \label{fig.SICAPI}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.40\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Subfigure b}
    \label{fig.painel_sicapi}
\end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.40\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-c}
        \caption{Subfigure c}
        \label{fig.SICAPI}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.40\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{Subfigure d}
    \label{fig.painel_sicapi}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Image}
    \label{fig.sicapi}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, that's actually what I want. Sorry for the neglection of document class. I am fresh, and I will take note of that. Thank you again for your timely reply.